# Mac Lion Python modules - not installing in the right location

Tags: python, macos, osx-lion

I'm trying to upgrade some of my Python modules - in particular: matplotlib, scipy and numpy.

I've tried using macports and easy_install with no luck. I think they are being installed in the wrong place..

From macports I get:

```
matty$ port installed
......... snip .........
py27-ipython @0.13.1_0+scientific (active)
py27-matplotlib @1.2.0_1+tkinter (active)
py27-numpy @1.6.2_1 (active)
python27 @2.7.3_1 (active)
```

So as far as I can see from macports, I have matplotlib version 1.2 and numpy version 1.6 installed. However, when I check Python I get:

```
matty$ python --version
Python 2.7.3

matty$ python
>>> import numpy
>>> print numpy.__version__
1.5.1

>>> import matplotlib
>>> print matplotlib.__version__
1.0.1
```

Using easy_install I get some sandbox error:

```
matty$ sudo easy_install -U numpy
......... snip .........
error: SandboxViolation: open('/dev/null', 'w') {}
```

I'm guessing there is a PATH error somewhere - and that's a guess! Any help is much appreciated.

edit:

```
matty$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python
```

This is a link:

```
matty$ ls -l python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  24 27 Feb 13:34 python -> /opt/local/bin/python2.7
matty$ ls -l python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  73 22 Oct 21:14 python2.7 ->   
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

$PYTHONPATH:

```
matty$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/local/scisoft/packages/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
```

Done this:

```
matty$ export PYTHONPATH=

matty$ python
>>> import numpy
>>> print numpy.__version__
1.6.2
>>> import matplotlib
>>> print matplotlib.__version__
1.2.0
```

Seems to have worked!

Comment: Type `which python` and post the result.

Comment: matty$ which python
    /opt/local/bin/python

Comment: Do you have `$PYTHONPATH` configured?

Comment: I'm not sure, is that the sys.path stuff?

Comment: No, just `echo $PYTHONPATH` in your shell.

Comment: Ah, I get `matty$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/local/scisoft/packages/python/lib/python2.6/site-packages/`

Comment: OK then.  `export PYTHONPATH=` (i.e. equals nothing) and re-run the tests from your question.

Comment: Edited above. Seems to have worked, many thanks for your help Trojan! You're a Gent!

Comment: One tip is to just ``print numpy`` etc so it tells you where it was loaded from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the environment variable `$PYTHONPATH` set to a non-standard location (outside of the Macports Python installation directory).

If you clear `$PYTHONPATH` then your tests will work.

Once you have confirmed that, it's just a case of finding out where `$PYTHONPATH` is set (probably `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` or `/etc/profile`) and removing it.